# WMI Query DNS CNAME in subdomains

Tags: c#, powershell, dns, wmi

I am trying to write the following PowerShell script in C# using WMI queries.

```
    Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName [DNS Server] | ? {$_.zonename} | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName [DNS Server] -RRType CNAME | ? {$_.Hostname -like "$DNSCname*"} | Format-Table
```

This snippet will query DNS and return all zones and pipe the results to Get-DnsServerResourceRecord which will then return all records the alias name (and it's variants) exists in.

For Example:
$DNSCname='ABCXYZ'

The Results are:

```
ABCXYZ.domain1.com
ABCXYZ123.subdomain.domain1.com
ABCXYZ456.subdomain.domain2.com
```

Unfortunately the following WMI query does not work for me.

```
    "SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord WHERE OwnerName LIKE '%ABCXYZ%'"
```

Is there a way to write a WMI query that will return the same results as the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% certain that this provider doesn't support filtering that way (but I can't find a reference). You'll have to get all of them and filter them in your code, which incidentally is exactly what's happening in the PowerShell code (you're letting the cmdlet, which itself is a thin wrapper around the WMI objects, return all the results and then filtering by using `?` / `Where-Object`).